# File provider using node.js with json and HTTP request with sails/express.js (web service)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, sails.js

I'm trying to create a controller that provides files. The purpose is to share source code file between application, the files are requested when the server is lanched and then cached.

My code works, until the JSON response.

```
    for(var i in files){
        data[files[i]] = {};
        for(var j in extensions){
            var filePath = __config.path.base + 'shared/lib/public/' + files[i] + '.' + extensions[j];
            if(fs.existsSync(filePath)){
                data[files[i]][extensions[j]] = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
            }else{
                data[files[i]][extensions[j]] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    var message = new __message('Request performed, see data.', data, true);
    console.log(__format.response(message));

    var message = new __message('test', ['dsds', 'yes'], true);

    res.send(__format.response(message));
```

The first message is the one I want to send back, the second was for test. The console.log works well, I see the content of my files.

But I don't get anything on the webpage with the first message, I mean, I got everything exept the 'data' content.

I guess that the content is too big (around 100000 characters), how can I fix it?

**Edit:**
The issue is from res.send, I tried res.json but still the same. I tried to send only one file (2k characters) but still the same.
I use sails, based on express.js.

**Edit2:**
***After set as plain/text:***

```
    var message = __format.response(new __message('Request performed, see data.', data, true));
    console.log(message)
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': message.length
    })
    res.send(message);
```

**Console**:

```
[2014-01-26 02:20:40.719] [INFO] console - { m: 'Request performed, see data.',
  d: 
   [ Format: { ts: '///<reference path=\'./../def/defLoader.d.ts\'/>\r\n\r\n.....}',
       js: false } ],
  s: true,
  t: 'm' }
```

But now I don't have anything rendered on the page, or it takes a while (several minutes).
And I finally got the same.

```
{
  "m": "Request performed, see data.",
  "d": [],
  "s": true,
  "t": "m"
}
```

Comment: you don't provide the problematic code then, we should see how you construct the message. these `__` seem custom and we don't know what they do

Comment: The mesage code is too big and not what's important here. If I do a console.log(message) I see correctly the message text, the data (files) and the status. A message is basically composed of these three things, user message, data and status. Files are stored as text in data.

Comment: is the `__format.response(message)` a string?

Comment: The `console.log(__format.response(message));` display a correct content too, the issue is about `res.send()` here, it's too big I guess...

Comment: __format will convert the message into Object, not JSON. *

Comment: JSON string or object? it matters

Comment: I tried using __format.responseJSON and I got `{"m":"Request performed, see data.","d":[],"s":true,"t":"m"}`

Comment: I tried object and string, both the same.

Comment: you can't send an object in the web, you must serialize it and then deserialise it. To send `var response = {'m':'g'}` through web, you must send `JSON.stringify(response)` string and then on the other side you must `JSON.parse(response)` to make string into json object again. Console log won't help you, it makes everything into string, you should check with typeof or instanceof

Comment: That's not the issue here, my __format classe take care of that, if I use the `var message = new __message('test', ['dsds', 'yes'], true);` it's correctly converted into a string that I can convert into object in the other side. The issue is the size of the string I guess.

Comment: tell me what headers you use to send the response

Comment: I don't precise any header, it's `express.js` default header used here, I don't know really.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set

Comment: set, text/plain and content length, it is the length or the json string...and send

Comment: It looks like you're right, if I just send the content displayed on the console, it works. So the size is not the issue here.

Comment: I tried to set `{Format: {js: false, ts: "///<reference path=\'./../def/defLoader.d.ts\'/>\r\n\r\n/**\r\n...` instead of data in the message and I got the content correctly. So, it's the way the fs.readFileAsync returns the content that is not compatible with res.send(). I tried to convert into string but nothing so far.

Comment: in your code i see only sync...do you have an async code and you make any mistake with it?

Comment: I do it synch because I wanted to send back all files at the same time. But that's not the issue neither. I made many try and it works when I send directly the file content, I really don't understand the issue here and I'm tired...

Comment: If I do `return res.json(data['Format']);` it works. If I do `return res.json(data);` I got an empty array. Why?

Comment: If I do: `return res.send(__format.response('Request performed, see data.', {file: 'Format', content: data['Format']}, true));` it works. If I do `return res.send(__format.response('Request performed, see data.', data, true));` it gives me empty data array. I still don't understan the issue here, I will use the format that works, and request file one by one, in several HTTP requests.

Comment: you have problems when you don't use well libraries, try to figure out what every api function does exactly and then continue. Start with simple things and then advance deeper. I can't provide any further help, I am sorry

Comment: It works now with another controller, that manage only one file at the same time. I'm still working on the one that manages several files at the same time.

Comment: Honnestly I think that the problem is not from my code, but it could be a Express.js or nodejs issue, I have no way to know that. It's not normal that if I put the file content in an object it works and when I put it in a sub object it doesn't, I used the debugger on my code and it's not from my method, it returns the entire object correctly. The issue happens at res.send(), not before.